# Latex algorithm cross-column typesetting

Tags: algorithm, latex, multiple-columns

How to use latex to implement the multi-column algorithm in the link below, thank you very much.
[multi-column algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftwNr.png)

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321750/listing-source-code-in-two-columns) help?

Comment: Can you please make a [mre] of how far you already come yourself? E.g. can you write the algorithm in one column as a starting point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your suggestions, I finally solved it using "\begin{multicols}{n}" and "\end{multicols}".

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{algorithm*}[h]
\begin{multicols}{3} //three columns
// your code
}
\end{multicols}
\end{algorithm*}
```